# Is "Too old to migrate" a good reason NOT to migrate?

Tags: discussion, migration, migrated-questions, old-questions, declined-flags

I flagged this question: [Tetris-ing an array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3275258/561731) with a note:

> Should this not be moved to codegolf? It is that type of question...

And I got the response:

> declined - Too old to migrate.

What does that mean? CodeGolf did not exist when this question was posted, and now it does, so it should be **migrated**

We have done this before countless times, especially with many questions which used to be on Stack Overflow and now are here on meta.

As shown by the selected answer here: [Should we migrate old questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8004/155556), We **should** be migrating old questions.

Comment: Well, meta is different. I believe programmers specifically asked us to stop migrating super-old SO content (even though it might have been on-topic for there) because stuff from 2008 all has like a kajillion votes on it, which swamps new content even though it's from a difference place. I guess the same thinking applies to other SE sites.

Comment: @AakashM see the linked question in my OP

Comment: This should not be migrated because I would lose repz. REPZ! REPZ! MAH PRECIOUS REPZ!

Comment: @Pekka haha oy... :-P

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA 80 views last active 2 years ago doesn't smell like current consensus to me, but let's see :)

Comment: @AakashM [another answer by Jeff Atwood](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/87578/155556) along the same lines.

Comment: What is the point of flagging mods to migrate an old question that is on-topic and already has a bunch of answers?

Comment: @Won't how is a code golf question **on-topic** on Stack Overflow?

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA: Its code, isn't it?  Programming, and all?  They were on topic before CG existed.  That doesn't necessarily mean they are off topic now, its just that we have a site dedicated for this.  Again, answer my question--why bother trolling old questions that are on topic (even ever so slightly ones) for migration?

Comment: @Won't usually a Stack Overflow  shows some effort on the OPs part. No offense to Pekka, but that question does not cut it, and is **Asking** the SO community to do the coding for him, which is **not constructive** on Stack Overflow. I did not troll at all, someone posted their answer in SE chat and I noticed that it had no reason to be on SO.

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA: There's a difference between old, answered questions which can be migrated, and new, unanswered questions which can be migrated.  The big one being that mods on the target site will chew your ass out if you migrate the old ones.  If its old, answered, and on topic, just let sleeping dogs lie.  If it sucks, vote to close the damn thing.  Its such a low priority thing that requires a lot of work to handle properly, it just isn't worth it.

Comment: @Won't that is why I voted to close as "not constructive", but I also flagged for the mods for migration.

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA: Please don't flag old, answered, on-topic questions for migration.

Comment: @Won't it is **NOT** on-topic. read my comment above. Those types of questions are **not** on topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA: it *is* on topic.  Barely, yes, but on topic.  Would we migrate if asked today?  Yep.  Do we have to spend all this effing effort on old, answered, on-topic (barely or not) questions?  HELL NO.  It is ***low priority***.  Handling flags like this requires ***disproportionately more effort for their value***.  Therefore leave it be.

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA - seriously, why are you wasting our time with this? Vote to close and move on, *please*.

Comment: `@`amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA: Quoting @DavidZaslavsky (cannot find link, from memory) "The existence of another SE site does _not_ change on-topicness of a question". Sites _can_ have overlap regions (as a [chemistry.SE] mod, I've already had to deal with these with [physics.SE] and [biology.SE]). The general rules for dealing with these is that they be moved to wherever they shall get a better answer (unless the tone of the question clearly tells you which site it ought to be on). The tetris one has some good answers (though @pekka hasn't accepted any). It won't be helped _much_ from migration.

Comment: @Manish yeah. I'm hesitant to accept one because I did want to test 'em all - which I'm not getting around to at the moment....

Comment: @Pekka: So it's not a "I want MOAR answers" issue, right? Migration for overlaps is when the question needs(and can get) better answers, like I said.

Comment: @Manish yeah. I'm sure the question is well answered. (just explaining why I haven't accepted any yet)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes, "too old" is a good reason not to migrate. Old questions are of very low value, and when old questions go from SO (with the matching crazy high views/votes) **they're very disruptive to smaller communities**: piles of free rep and badges for the owners of the migrated posts, the question looks disproportionately good via upvotes, the tone of the question/answers are from another site...

For an example, let's look at [Difference between UI and UX](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/7174/difference-between-ui-and-ux) (10k only), an old Stack Overflow question migrated to User Experience. The answers are from *programmers*, and it shows. It *really really shows*. The top voted answer is a couple of links to Wikipedia and a "Well I guess it means this". As a mod I've strongly considered deleting this question and starting over.

**There's not much you can *do* with an old question**. The asker has probably moved on, the answerers don't care, and all the voting in the world (practically speaking) won't fix that *terrible* answer being highly upvoted and *accepted*.

Note the "yes" argument is from a 3 year old question when the network was considerably smaller. The mood seems to have settled much more toward letting communities organically grow, and tossing old questions, especially to *Beta* sites, doesn't help them do that.

Comment: Related reading: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/ (especially the last bullet point under "Respecting other communities").

Comment: I used to think that migrating old questions was a good idea - I don't think that any longer. It makes setting the tone and scope of the new site *that* much harder.

Comment: Torch the question on UX. Nobody will miss it.

Comment: @sixlettervariables I have dupes to reroute...been meaning to post a Q to replace it myself (and appear highly suspicious for doing so) but never got around to it

Comment: Sure flooding new sites with old questions from [SO] is harmful. But they're less disruptive if they are migrated only gradually, which is roughly the current system. An old question will only be migrated if a user comes across it and makes an affirmative judgement that it is relevant for the proposed target.

Comment: "disruptive to smaller communities" - that seems a good enough reason in and of itself.

Comment: "Old questions are of very low value" - This seems contrary to the spirit of SE sites which encourages long-term maintenance of the knowledge collected.

Comment: @ArnaudMeuret old questions on your site have some value. Old questions from other people are basically trash. It's not from your community, the original posters don't care...it's just trash someone floated over to your community in most cases. If it's valuable, it will be asked by people who care in the right community and will have a much better chance of being maintained than "oh, THAT question from Stack Overflow"

Comment: MMm I see your point, you're basically saying that if it was a good question it would have been migrated earlier but this does not account for the case of the old and good question created on the _wrong_ site because the correct one did not yet exist. I came to this discussion from [this good off-topic question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130329/how-do-you-get-what-a-symbolic-link-points-to-without-grep/) which every reader wants to migrate to [unix.se]

Comment: This is unsound reasoning. "Old questions are of very low value": *false*. The questions that help me the most are often years old. "they're very disruptive to smaller communities": *not necessarily true*. First, a question that is at the wrong site is already a disruptive presence by dint of that fact: at least post-migration it would no longer be a category error. As for rep/etc, some questions would not be disruptive at all; others could have their upvotes reset or scaled according to the relative size of the source and target communities.

Comment: "*Old questions are of very low value*" - Based on what? Tons of "old" questions are still solutions to common problems seen today. The only difference is, they're on the wrong site.. Just because the question was asked in 2009 doesn't mean the question isn't still being asked today, thus being searched to this day. When they wind up on the "wrong" site, it builds a first impression, and may cause people to misinterpret the purpose of the site.

Comment: " Old questions are of very low value" that's generalizing to a huge degree, and letting it sit as a highly upvoted Q/A on the original site does more harm than it does good. Let the other  site make mince-meat out of the answers instead. I guess that [Gilles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/137931/176060) explained that closing it and reasking when necessary is a good workaround, as it won't migrate the old answers including the rep. But besides that, the fact that a question is old doesn't make it bad, I don't know how you can start off with that premise.

Answer (score 11):

"Too old to migrate" is now ingrained into the system.  For example, this question can now not be migrated:

[image: Too old dialogue on Meta Stack Overflow]

This also applies on main sites, and **the restriction includes community ♦ moderators**.  Therefore with these changes it is no longer *possible* to migrate the question even if it is a valid request without developer intervention which may be likely to result in flags being declined in the future.

Comment: I recently got a declined flag as "too old to migrate" in Stack Overflow, what happened to that system?

Comment: @JMCF125 If you raised it as an 'other' flag for community moderator attention asking to have it migrated to another site and it was an old  post then I'd imagine a moderator declined your flag as they couldn't migrate the question either

Comment: Am I misunderstanding this or is "too old to migrate" not showing on any of the questions that are too old to migrate on any of the sites? ![SO](http://i.imgur.com/YWgvrUm.png) ![SU](http://i.imgur.com/uJS71BT.png) ![SF](http://i.imgur.com/CutalSm.png)

Answer (score 5):

The age of the question doesn't matter, actually (there are many voices who say that, but I've never seen any justification that the age is directly relevant). What matters is:

- Is the question on-topic on the source site? Just because it is now also on-topic on another site doesn't automatically make it off-topic where it is.
- Does the question (or its answers) have a lot of upvotes? Questions should not be migrated if they already have too many votes compared to the typical amount on the destination site, because that would make it impossible for the destination site to rate it correctly. This is sometimes related to the age of the question (older questions have had more time to gather votes), but not always — a 1-hour old question on SO with 50 upvotes is already too old to migrate to most other sites, but a 3-year old question with no votes can be migrated if a good destination is found.
- Is the question high-quality, and does it have worthwhile answers? Otherwise, it's best to close the existing question and ask a similar (or better) one on the new site.

Comment: This is logical. It's not built off the assumption that old questions hold no value (no proof). This answer focuses on the philosophy of Stack Exchange, rather than the philosophy of "age affects value". In fact, *not* migrating older questions can lead to bad first impressions, which could result in more users posting on the wrong site, which is the real disruption.

Answer (score 3):

> ...**be extremely reluctant to migrate old, answered questions**. The votes and answers on these reflect the opinions and work of the community where they originated, and in most cases they’ll be somewhat out of place elsewhere – you want your [greatest hits](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/stack-exchanges-greatest-hits/) to reflect the best that your community has to offer, not someone else’s. And, again, the migration can come across as rude: if someone has invested serious effort into an answer and has linked to it on their blog or from their résumé, then snatching it from them without due consideration won’t endear them to you. Only migrate these questions when the alternative is deletion.

Quote source: [Respect the community – your own, and others’](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/), posted Mar 22 2012.

Comment: "*without due consideration*" - But what about consideration of site intent? Should we be more worried about those specific users than the intentions of the site, which may affect an unbounded amount of users to this day?

Comment: disagree with 60 days rule for EVERY topic. Finding a good answer for a site handling specialized topics might take days to think over and do some research. Also a specialized topic has higher chances to get answer faster in a specialized community. So I think this has not been thought over deeply enough. Think of the support desk: you have 1st level who are more or less advanced users themselves, so a technical question brings you to the 2nd level, but if you go to further levels, it can take even more time. Topics and question complexity can be very different.