# Is it possible to migrate questions to a beta SE site?

Tags: discussion, support

Specifically, [I need this baby in a month - send me nine women!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76526/i-need-this-baby-in-a-month-send-me-nine-women), is a classic question that all project managers need to see.  Would it be possible to migrate it to http://pm.stackexchange.com?

Here is the question for those that cannot see it:

> **I need this baby in a month - send me nine women! [closed]**
>
> Under what circumstances - if any - does adding programmers to a team actually speed development of an already late project?

Comment: They do have a similar question on PM asking how to resist the addition of new resources to a late project, and when it's acceptable to add them.  [Adding new team members to a late project](http://pm.stackexchange.com/q/1395/25)

Comment: @BilltheLizard - move and merge? the top answer on the deleted question is actually pretty useful.

Comment: I'll ask the PM mods if they want it, but at that age and with that many votes from SO I'm doubtful.

Comment: I asked the PM mods and they declined.  I'm thinking about writing a blog post on this topic so at least the top answer and one or two others won't be completely deleted from the Internet.

Comment: @BilltheLizard thanks, maybe leave a url here?

Comment: Sure, no problem.

Comment: I just noticed on Twitter that the OP is annoyed at the question being deleted.  I'm sure stealing it for my blog would be a big mistake.  I'm trying to work out a better solution.

Comment: @BilltheLizard yeah, that's where this all started. Hopefully this turns out with a happy ending.

Comment: I ended up just clearing out about half of the answers and locking the question.

Comment: @BilltheLizard awesome, you da man!

Answer (score 13):

Any SO moderator has the ability to migrate questions to any site, whether they should do that in this specific case is a different matter.

I can't see the question in this example (10k-only), but I suspect that it's highly voted on and with a lot of answers from programmers. Posts on a smaller beta site usually have no chance to compete with highly upvoted migrated questions, those migrated posts will stick to the list of highest voted questions for a long while. Other problems are that the answers are probably written from a different perspective by a different audience.

The decision whether to migrate this question lies with the target site, if their moderators think that it would be valuable to them, they can request a migration.

Comment: Interesting, perhaps for beta sites, the question could be migrated without the attendant votes?

Comment: Voting is a big problem with migrated questions, but not the only one. I don't think migrating an old question with that many answers would do the target site any good, reposting a variant of it if it would be interesting would be the better alternative, as ChrisF suggested.

Answer (score 9):

This is an old question that has 45 (yes forty five) answers and a vote count of +190 / -7.

I fail to see what benefit there would be in migrating such a beast to any other site, let alone a beta site. If you really think that the question should be asked on the project management site repost it.

For the benefit of those with less than 10,000 reputation I reproduce the question in all it's glory.

> **I need this baby in a month - send me nine women!**
>
> Under what circumstances - if any - does adding programmers to a team actually speed development of an already late project?

Yes that's it. Better to let sleeping dogs lie I think.

Comment: I would disagree unless the question already exists there.  I did check but not all that closely.  From my experience this is a classical project blunder, one that all PMs need not only to be aware of but to be continually reminded why it doesn't work.

Comment: @tvanfosson - I was specifically referring to migration with my last sentence.

Comment: I understood and, apparently, the question has been asked there but in a different form.  It would be nice to resuscitate the accepted answer in the current question though, if possible on the new site in some form.

Answer (score 2):

- Migration to beta sites is perfectly possible. My answer to [Is there a hash function with 2048bit output?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/985) was migrated to [Cryptography Beta](http://crypto.stackexchange.com).
- I can't see the question you linked to (10k only), but judging by its ID, it's pretty old.

  Just yesterday, somebody started the Meta discussion [Is “Too old to migrate” a good reason NOT to migrate?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136537). The consensus seems to be yes, especially if the question has a high number of upvotes.
- If you're certain that your specific question would contribute to the target site and it doesn't have too much upvotes to disturb its [greatest hits](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/stack-exchanges-greatest-hits/), state your case in [Project Management Beta's Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/380/project-management).

Answer (score 2):

The question seems rather broad, to be acceptable. Even if it were not too broad, I would consider these points before migrating it. Migration can be done from moderators, but as far as I recall, they don't generally migrate old questions.

- Do new answers have a chance to appear on top? If there is an answer with a score of (for example) 15, is there any chance any new answers would get a higher score, considering the number of existing answers?
- Is there any chance the OP would notice the question has been migrated, and choose a different answer as accepted (if there is already one that is accepted)?