# Why was this question related to uninstalling the Oracle Database Client deleted?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question

[How to uninstall / completely remove Oracle 11g (client)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450726/how-to-uninstall-completely-remove-oracle-11g-client/8450982) was just recently deleted, after having been closed as "off-topic".

It was asked on 2011-12-09, had 13 upvotes, 3 favorites, and was viewed 69,898 times.

Per https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic :

> ... but if your question generally covers…
>
> - software tools commonly used by programmers
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

I think that the Oracle Database Client certainly falls into this category.

In full disclosure, I had the only answer posted to the question before it was closed - and it had earned 25 up-votes.

If this is considered off-topic for SO, what other site would better be considered on-topic?

Would a moderator be able to move this to the correct site, instead of having this knowledge essentially lost forever?

Now that the question has been deleted, I think the risk has just increased that new duplicate questions will be asked in its place.

Comment: Nothing is lost forever. And given that you have a blog [why not post it there](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:sjVbJ5wIvkwJ:stackoverflow.com/questions/8450726/how-to-uninstall-completely-remove-oracle-11g-client+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk) in the mean time?

Comment: That question is too old to migrate to a different site.

Comment: Depending on the question, it sounds either like a SuperUser question (ie, how to do something on a computer) or a DBA question (though most likely SuperUser).

Comment: @Bart - good point.  I could, but it was already cited from another site.  My concern is that it was valuable to and on SO, or at least, the SE community.  I'd rather have the post here, where others could (and have) helped to improve the content, SE-style, than on more of a "static" blog.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName - Maybe you can repeat this as an answer so that this question can be completed?  Also, what defines "too old"?  Is there a source that can be cited?

Comment: @ziesemer http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days

Comment: @Joe - Thanks.  Someone please post this as an answer (or I will, eventually) - so that we don't end up with http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117251/what-to-do-with-questions-that-have-been-self-resolved-as-a-comment-instead-of-a .  :-)

Comment: http://superuser.com/q/256762/

Comment: @RobertHarvey So if I ask [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/235839/119477) on SuperUser which would be on topic there, it would be okay if the SO question got closed and deleted?

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter: How did you arrive at that conclusion?

Comment: @RobertHarvey - thanks for the find!

Comment: @RobertHarvey seems to have many of the same properties as this one. Short question. A bit of a bike shed. On topic on both SO and SU. Too old to migrate. What's the difference?

Comment: I don't think pushing off our problem questions on other sites is the answer.

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter Note that the SU question is 9 months older than the copy on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Would a moderator be able to move this to the correct site, instead of having this knowledge essentially lost forever?

No. The question is [older than 60 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days), which makes it too old to migrate to a different site, [even for diamond moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/158330/191706).

> Now that the question has been deleted, I think the risk has just increased that new duplicate questions will be asked in its place.

New questions which are duplicates of the deleted one will end up closed or migrated.

I don't have enough rep to view the question, but questions about installing or uninstalling software - even if it's software used to aid programming - belong on SuperUser. Unless it's operations software for use on servers in a professional setting, then it belongs on ServerFault.

If you really think a deleted question should stick around, you can vote to undelete if you have enough rep. It's not possible in this case, however, because a moderator cast a binding delete vote, and you can't vote to undelete moderator deleted questions (thanks Martin Smith for pointing this out).

Comment: A moderator put in the final delete vote so voting to undelete is not possible.

Answer (score 9):

It seems strange to post all of the stats about the question and not post the question itself.

> How to uninstall / completely remove Oracle 11g (client)?
>
> deinstall.bat doesn't work.

That's the entire question.

And your answer is a bulleted list copied (with full attribution) from [Oracle-Base: Manual Oracle Uninstall](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/manual-oracle-uninstall.php).  That page already appears in Google search results, so I don't see why we need an exact duplicate of it here as well.

Comment: This. It's a terrible question and it should not be on SO (and hence, clogging search indexes) in any shape or form.

Comment: It's already on SuperUser anyway.  http://superuser.com/q/256762

Comment: @Pekka웃 Is it also a terrible question on SuperUser?

Comment: @RobertHarvey *sigh* With a very similar level of quality...

Comment: The linked answer from Oracle-Base is by far not complete.

Answer (score 1):

If it's an interesting question that deserves answering, then you should post the question at SuperUser, and answer it yourself (with your previous answer if you wish).  It won't have any votes, but if it's good and useful it will garner them over time.

Comment: Already posted at SuperUser.  http://superuser.com/q/256762