# Why can I vote to reopen a deleted question?

Tags: bug, deleted-questions, reopen-closed

I've just voted to reopen [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266164/should-edit-or-other-similar-monikers-be-allowed-in-questions-or-answers) even though it has been deleted. Screenshot (there were 2 reopen votes already, mine is the third one):

[image]

Is this a bug?

Comment: I think this is one of the very rare cases where the author, who deleted his own answer, also happen to be a moderator, so we can't vote to undelete, otherwise anyone voting to reopen would also vote to undelete, I guess.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This has been discussed on Meta.SE previously](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190443/why-can-i-vote-to-reopen-a-deleted-question).

In short, [Shog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9) [said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222671/163863):

> It probably makes more sense to disable the reopen vote in these cases and just direct the voter to either vote to undelete, flag, or raise the issue here on Meta.

However, he also said:

> Given the frequency with which this happens, it's not a pressing issue in any case.

... so I wouldn't expect it to be "fixed" any time soon.