# Why can deleted questions be reopened but not closed?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, deleted-questions, vote-to-reopen

You can vote to reopen a deleted question, as shown in the below screenshots:

[image]

[image: Screenshot showing reopen vote recorded]

However, you cannot vote to close deleted questions; if you try you just get a popup that says "this question is now deleted" as shown in the below screenshot:

[image: Screenshot showing popup message]

Why are reopening and closing treated differently vis-à-vis deleted questions?

(I am aware of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190443/why-can-i-vote-to-reopen-a-deleted-question), but it treats the issue as a bug, and doesn't discuss closing at all.)

Comment: Quick question for you: why would it need to be an option? Deleted means it's irrelevant whether open or closed in most respects.

Comment: @RoryAlsop If it’s relevant then you shouldn’t be able to reopen it either.

Comment: You need the opportunity for it to be edited into something that is worth reopening.

Comment: @RoryAlsop Closed/open status doesn’t affect ability to edit.

Comment: of course not. That's not what I said though.

Comment: @RoryAlsop What opportunity are you referring to then?