# Should I vote to close old questions?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons, broken-windows

I just stumbled upon a question from 2009 (that's what I mean by 'old'), [and it's this one for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814600/multilanguage-in-wpf).

I think we can all agree that by Today's standards this question would be closed (with a couple of valid reasons to choose from).

However, things were different back then - well from what I can gather, I see quite a few questions like this from back in the day. This kind of question was clearly acceptable at one point.

So, should I vote to close it or leave it be? And just for extra understanding, what would happen to any rep for that question and the answers if it was closed?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

View all question with today's standards. If the question fits as per [current standards](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) then leave it open; if it doesn't fit then vote/flag to close it. If we keep the questions which don't fit as per current standards, then people will ask why the questions are still open.

Comment: fair enough, but what will happen to the rep all those users have gained? My conscience is the only reason I came to Meta to clarify, I am not sure I agree with people losing rep that they earned, just because rules have changed

Comment: @musefan - We don't lose reputation if our question get closed. So you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: So in my example, Jonathan wont lose the 65 rep he gained from upvotes? And the accepted answer wont lose the 80 rep?

Comment: @musefan Reputation is lost when the question is deleted, not just closed. Questions are only deleted if they serve no purpose whatsoever.

Comment: @musefan - They won't. It's worth to look at [How does “Reputation” work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7237/187824) :)

Comment: @DuncanJones: OK, that's cool, I can sleep better now

Comment: @DuncanJones for the sake of precision, reputation is sometimes kept even if question is deleted, see [Deleted posts should not influence reputation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124754/165773) post here at MSO: _"you should keep the reputation for... * A score of 3 or greater * Visible on the site for at least 60 days"_

Answer (score -2):

Not if your reason to close is "this site belongs on another site on the StackExchange network", because that option is absent for me on [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121035/how-do-i-create-a-new-beamer-environment-with-a-verbatim-environment), so I can only assume that such closes are not desired.

Comment: Questions older than 60 days cannot be migrated, not even by Moderators.

Comment: Generally speaking, questions that should be migrated are off-topic on the current site, so yes, you should close them as "off-topic -> some other reason", rather than "off-topic -> belongs on..."

Comment: But that seems perverse. Why are we supposed to censor the existence of these other sites? I'm sure this is an unintended consequence of a technical decision...

Comment: @RobinGreen it wasn't a technical decision actually, it was done for other purposes (mostly tied to high numbers of votes and associated badges & privileges in the destination community. See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days) and [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136537/is-too-old-to-migrate-a-good-reason-not-to-migrate?rq=1) for more info.